# Suspending a curl command in bash that is downloading a file

Tags: bash, curl

I have a large file that I am downloading using curl:

```
curl -s https://raw.github.... | bash
```

If I suspend this job with `ctrl+z`, and then resume it again with say `fg %1` will that file still download correctly?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I tried and it seemed to resume ok... But I dont think the download will finish for hours possibly days on current connection... I think if I could, I would suspend it and resume it when I have a faster connection...

Comment: I haven't seen piping curl into bash before. What does that do, or can you point me to documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah Im not too sure to be honest... The full command is:
    curl -s https://raw.github.com/xdissent/ievms/master/ievms.sh | bash
I am following the instructions on this page: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/04/internet-explorer-for-mac-ie7-ie8-ie-9-free/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will, as long as the socket hasn't timed out!

Answer (score 1):

`wget` background&&continue downloading maybe help.
But it also depends on the webserver's functionality. Some of them don't allow range downloading.

```
$ wget -b -c http://www.website.com/download/hello.txt
   -b
   --background
       Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.
   -c
   --continue
       Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by
       another program.
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out wget I will definitely use it in future... I feel I have already dowloaded too much to restart my download with a different command though...